# How to add more than one view iPad View Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

I am making a simple application and will require to actually load different views on a button click.

The thing is I want to separate the code for each view into it's own class as I don't want it all put into one controller.

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this and also the possibility to show how to switch between views?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Assign a view controller for each tab and it should behave as you want. There are quite a few tutorials on creating it. You can look at [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/13/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-tabbarview-to-switch-between-views/).

Comment: Never knew a Tab Bar Controller was so easy to work with! Thanks a lot